# Can I prevent exposing 'details' of 3rd party library through public API?

Tags: c#, .net, api-design

I'm creating a library that is a wrapper of and an extension to a 3rd party library. Is there a way to prevent unintentionally exposing the 3rd party library? Or at least get a warning about it? I don't want users of my library to reference (depend on) the 3rd party library.

For example it is possible to do:

```
public class MyLibraryClass
{
    public void Use3rdParty(3rdPartyClass c)
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

I'm aware that marking the method as internal will solve the problem. What annoys me is that I've made mistakes and exposed some methods that should have been internal. I want to avoid this in the future.

Additionally, I want to ask whether it is safe to have public implicit conversions from 3rd party class:

```
public class MyLibraryClass
{
    public static implicit operator MyLibraryClass(3rdPartyClass c)
    {
        // Conversion...
    }
}
```

Operators have to be defined as static and public so this method cannot be internal. From my thinking it should be safe because outside of my library the user should not be able to see this conversion method and therefore even try this conversion.

Overall, I'm not worried about security so I don't mind that with reflection user can access 'anything'. It's more about having the API clean and not to confuse the users.

I'm using VS 2010 and .NET 4.0.

**EDIT:** To sum up and clarify, my problem is that you can unintentionally (by accident) expose some 3rd party library details and you don't get any warning by compiler or anything. I'm looking for some way to tell the compiler that an assembly should be used only in places with internal or lower access.

Comment: Does `3rdPartyData` reside in the third parties assembly?

Comment: @Liam: The class is defined in the 3rd party library and used in my library (I changed the name to be 3rdPartyClass instead of 3rdPartyData).

Comment: Can you move to VS 2015? It is a LOT easier in 2015 to make "[code rule checkers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx)" like you want.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Unfortunately, I'm stuck with VS 2010 (at least in this project). But thanks for the link. It is nice to see all the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you have implicit conversion operators, Visual Studio will ask anyone consuming your library that they have a reference to any types referred to in those operators. It is the same if you have any types which implement interfaces in the 3rd party library.

You could use Roslyn to do this sort of thing, but it sounds like you're using an older version of Visual Studio so that may not be an option.

Another option would be to use reflection to build a list of types from the 3rd party library, then use reflection to scan the public/protected members of the public types in your libraries to see if any of them use those types. Add this as a "unit" test or something which runs automatically as part of your build process.

You can obtain the list of types in an assembly with the following:

```
Type[] types = typeof(SomeTypeInAnAssembly).Assembly.GetTypes()
```

With the list of types in the 3rd party assembly and then you can iterate through the types in your assembly and check each constructor (`type.GetConstructors`), each property (`type.GetProperties`), each field (`type.GetFields`). These methods take a `BindingFlags` value, you will want to specify public and non-public, instance and static to get all methods. Then you will want to filter for things which are public (`IsPublic` property) or protected (`IsFamily` property on the `MemberInfo` structure). Check the types of the parameters for methods/constructors as well as the return types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (unfortunately, I cannot up-vote, yet).This is actually something that would solve the problem. Having something like unit test that will guard the API is not a bad idea. Although I was looking for some simple 'one-click' solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with an observation:

> I don't want users of my library to reference (depend on) the 3rd party library. …
>
> ```
> public void Use3rdParty(3rdPartyClass c)
> ```

You just forced the users of your API to depend on the third-party library. (They cannot call your API without having an third-party libary object ready to be passed in.)

That being said, what consists a good solution depends whether your own library mainly *extends* the third-party library, or whether it mainly uses that third-party library *as a private implementation detail*.

#### Your library mainly extends the third-party library:

I won't go into that further because I'm not sure your question even makes sense under this circumstance: If your library extends the third-party library, then its users are expected to use the third-party library already, therefore you don't need to hide it in the first place.

#### Your library uses the third-party library mainly as a private implementation detail:

Then you should *completely* hide the third-party library behind your own API. Which means that the third-party library's types may not appear at all in your own API's method signatures.

One good way (that comes with some minor overhead) is to wrap all of the third-party libary's types (or at least those that you'd otherwise be exposing) in your own wrapper classes:

```
namespace ThirdPartyLibrary
{
    public class ThirdPartyLibrary.Quux
    {
        public void Foo() { … }
        …
    }
}

namespace YourLibrary
{
    public sealed class Quux  // has same methods as the third-party library's type
    {
        private readonly ThirdPartyLibrary.Quux wrapped;
        …
        public Foo() { wrapped.Foo(); }  // forward calls to the underlying type
    }
}
```

and then write the remainder of your libary's public API in terms of these wrapper classes (which are also part of your API, btw.):

```
namespace YourLibrary
{
    public class Frobbler
    {
        public void Frobble(Quux c)
        {                // ^^^^
            …            // your wrapper class, not the third-party original 
        }
    }
}
```

(Additionally, it might be a good idea to merge the third-party DLL into your own ([by including it as an embedded resource and handling the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236495/can-i-prevent-exposing-details-of-3rd-party-library-through-public-api/29242734?noredirect=1#comment46693224_29242734), or by using a tool such as ILMerge) so that your library cannot possibly be deployed without the DLL only it might depend on.)

Comment: There is a easier way to merge than IL Merge, overriding `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` and [having it access a embedded resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx), the author of IL Merge even makes a comment on the article *"As the author of ILMerge, I think this is fantastic! If I had known about this, I never would have written ILMerge."*. There are even [libraries](https://libz.codeplex.com/) that build on top of it adding features like compressing the DLL and MEF discovery.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I knew about that possibility, but somehow never made the merntal connection to ILMerge. Thank you for adding this valuable piece of knowledge!

Comment: Even though there is nothing wrong with what you say, it is not an answer to my problem. Even with your solution I can, by mistake, use the 3rdPartyLibrary.Quux (in the Frobble method) and I will not get any warning until some user will complain. That is what bothers me. Erik's answer presents a solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a ViewModel or DTO (Data Transfer Object) to hide the implementation/detail of the 3rd Party library going forward.  This would provide an interface you have complete control of that is separate from any implementations of 3rd Party API's.

This way if you switch to another library you don't have to rewrite your API to match any new/switched/thrown own dependencies for the work you are doing and it's abstracted away from your API consumers as long as your don't expose those details in your new ViewModel or DTO.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was thinking along the same lines but my question was actually was actually more aimed at something else. See my edit of the question.